# Http server giving error 400 c# .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, http

I want to make a http server for testing. I am using the HttpListener class for  this purpose.

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
                listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:24578/");
                while (true)
                {
                    listener.Start();
                    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                    HandleRequest(context.Request);
                    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY><p>Test</br>Test new line</p></BODY></HTML>";
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                    context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    Stream output = context.Response.OutputStream;
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    output.Close();
                    listener.Stop();
                }
```

By connecting to http://localhost:24578/ I can see my website working fine as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1km0.png)

However, I would like to access my website from other devices connected to my network, so I opened cmd and typed ipconfig, my local ipv4 address is 192.168.1.108. So I opened in my browser http://192.168.1.108:24578/. It should be working fine as it's the same as localhost, but instead it shows me error 400 bad request, as shown[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkYZe.png)

Also, the web server does not receive the request since it doesn't write anything in the console (the method HandleRequest writes info about the request, and is never called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explicitly said that webserver only accept connections from localhost.
change this

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:24578/");
```

to

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:24578/");
```

You might need to run your application with administrator's right.

Comment: `listener.Prefixes.Add("http://0.0.0.0:24578/");`
This returns System.Net.HttpListenerException: The request is not supported, and 


`listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:24578/");`
returns System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

I didn't do the request in both cases, it was when preparing the server.

Update : using listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:24578/"); and running it as admin worked, thanks !